# Socket programming-rajay

Tags: sockets, socket.io, nsstream

Am using below mentioned code for receiving data  from the server by using socket programming. but receiving is not working here.but server connection and sending data are working fine.How to receive data from server.

```
       case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
                event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
                if (theStream == inputStream)
                {
                    uint8_t buffer[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                    {
                        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
                        NSLog(@"buffer %s",buffer);
                         NSLog(@"Received data--------------------%d", len);
                        if (len >= 0)
                        {
                            NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            NSLog(@"Received data--------------------%@", [output description]);
                             NSLog(@"buffer %s",buffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format it appropriately. First sentence should not be in all capitals. Code fragment should have each line starting with at least 4 spaces. And your are missing the Objective-C tag (and perhaps also IOS)

Comment: sorry...i edited. am expecting replay